# play audio on flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, flutter-dependencies, cross-platform

i am trying to play an audio via url in flutter. I'm using the audioplayers library: ^0.20.1, from the logs there seems to be no problems but I don't hear the audio coming out.

`AudioPlayer audio = AudioPlayer(); audio.play(myUrl)`

I assumed it was a permissions issue but it doesn't solve anything anyway

```
 await Permission.audio.request();
 if(await Permission.audio.isGranted)
{
  AudioPlayer audio = AudioPlayer();
  audio.play(myUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use latest version of [audio player](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) package
audioplayers: ^3.0.1

Follow these steps:

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
await player.setSourceUrl(url); // equivalent to setSource(UrlSource(url));
```

if you want to set the url and start playing, using the play shortcut:

```
await player.play(DeviceFileSource(localFile)); // will immediately start playing
```

For more info see the [documentation](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md)